# SQL SERVER Error de sintaxis en comando set tengo confusión entre la comilla simple y la doble

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo confusión entre las comillas simples y dobles.
Estoy usando la siguiente configuración, en el SP:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

declare @archivo nvarchar(40)
set @archivo = 'base.dbo.archivox'

SET @Script = 'INSERT INTO base.dbo.otroarchivo SELECT "'"campo título"'"+ , COUNT (*)  AS [campo1]
  FROM base.[dbo].[archivo2], '+ archivo + '
  WHERE ((Cantidad_del campo > 0) AND (TIPO = "'"J"'"))'

exec (@script)
```

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es tu duda...

Comment: Cómo dijo @jachguate no se entiende cúal es tu pregunta, te recomiendo que leas [Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edites tu pregunta para que puedas obtener una respuesta

Comment: Además, si quiere que el select diga SELECT 'campo titulo', va a devolver las palabras campo titulo y no el titulo del campo.

Comment: Perdón si no se entendió pero me da error de sintaxis por las comillas simples o las dobles.

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo de la siguiente manera:

```
 SET @Script = 'INSERT INTO base.dbo.otroarchivo SELECT 
''campo título''+ , COUNT (*)  AS [campo1] 
FROM base.[dbo].[archivo2], ''+ archivo + 
''WHERE ((Cantidad_del campo > 0) AND (TIPO = ''J''))'
```